# Minimal GDPR requirements for a website

Tags: gdpr

Currently I use cookiesandyou javascript service that provides a popup like "We use cookies here" with 3 options:

1. Agree
2. Decline
3. "Read more" link to a common page "What are cookies?"

Additionally I implemented the features to recall agreement, and to send request of obtaining or deletion  all personal data of a person. (which is email address he he..) and whole account.

I described types of an information the Service collect and it's purpose in Privacy section of my site. I use external analytics tool, which isn't Google but is GDRP compliant and started thoung Google Tags on user's agreement.

Is it enough to be compliant to GDPR? Don't I need to describe every group of my cookies if I store only necessary cookies how do some of websites and don't do others?

Comment: What happens when you click "Decline" on your website?

Comment: A special cookie is set like consent=false and analytics tool will not be loaded in further page loads. Only necessary cookies (sessid and consent) will be served.

Comment: Nobody answers, but as you describe it, your website seems more compliant to the GDPR as most websites I visit.